# Docker service does not start

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

docker is gigving me a hard time currently. I followed these [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) in order to install docker on my virtual server running Ubuntu 14.04 hosted by strato.de.

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Executing this line runs me directly into this error message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-042stab092.3/modules.builtin.bin'modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found.
Warning: current kernel is not supported by the linux-image-extra-virtual
 package.  We have no AUFS support.  Consider installing the packages  linux-image-virtual kernel and linux-image-extra-virtual for AUFS support.
```

After the installation was done, I installed the two mentioned packages. Now my problem is that I can't get docker to run.

```
service docker start
```

results in:

```
start: Job failed to start


docker -d
```

results in

```
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
ERRO[0000] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
WARN[0000] Running modprobe bridge nf_nat failed with message: , error: exit status 1
package not installed
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)
FATA[0000] Shutting down daemon due to errors: package not installed
```

and

```
docker run hello-world
```

results in

```
FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Does anybody have a clue about what dependencies could be missing? What else could have gone wrong? Are there any logs which docker provides?

I'm searching back and forth for a solution, but couldn't find one.

Just to mention this is a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 setup. I didn't install any other services except for java. And the reason why I need docker is for using the dockerimage of sharelatex.

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: Did you restart the host after install the packages?

Comment: Just did it again - didn't help. Does anybody know how to get that 'overlay' filesystem which docker asks for?

Comment: what is your kernel version? `uname -a`

Comment: 3.13.0-042stab092.3

I tried to upgrade to 3.18, but after rebooting it still says 3.13 . Using this approach http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/install-linux-kernel-to-3183-stable-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-peppermint

Comment: Why aren't you using apt-get? you should run `apt-get install linux-image-VERSION`

Comment: apt-get install says that I already have the newest version of 3.18, but it is still booting in 3.13

Comment: have you rebooted after installing the new kernel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what I tried/found out, hoping that it will save you some time or even help you solve it.

Docker's [download script](http://get.docker.com) is trying to identify the kernel through `uname -r` to be able to install the right kernel extras for your host.

I suspect two problems:

- My (united-hoster.de) and probably your provider use customized kernel images (eg. `3.13.0-042stab108.2`) for virtual hosts. Since the script is explicitly looking for `-generic` in the name, the lookup fails.
- While the naming problem would be easy to fix, I wasn't able to install the `generic` kernel extras with my hoster's custom kernel. It seems like using a upgrading the kernel does not work either, since it would affect all users/vHosts on the same physical machine. This is because the kernel is shared (stated in some support ticket).

To get around that ..

- I skipped it, hoping that Docker would work without AUFS support, but it didn't.
- I tried to force Docker to [use devicemapper](http://muehe.org/posts/switching-docker-from-aufs-to-devicemapper/) instead, but to no avail.

I see two options: get a *dedicated* host so you can mess with kernels and filesystems or a least let the docker installer do it or [install the binaries manually](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/).

Answer (score 10):

> You need to start docker

`sudo start docker`

and then

`sudo docker run hello-world`

I faced same problem on ubuntu 14.04, solved.

refer comment of Nino-K https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/issues/3

Comment: Unfortuantely it doesn't work as well.

FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution :(

Comment: just found out that godaddy's **dedicated servers** are actually virtual, a curse on `3.13.0-042stab108.2`

Comment: This should be the right answer. First install docker then run: `sudo docker start` and `sudo docker run hello-world` this worked for me

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but OP was unable to get the docker daemon to start, so this answer doesn't really help