# Does docker still doesn't run on virtual servers hosted by Strato now?

Tags: docker, server, virtual

during last winter I tried to get ShareLaTex running using its docker image. Back then the whole thing already failed with getting docker to run on my virtual Ubuntu 14.04 server. So today I decided to give it another try. The virtual server has a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 up and running.

After following the [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/) till the point of executing

```
docker images

docker run
```

or

```
docker run hello-world
```

I'll get this line returned:

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

So back in time, the discussion concluded that the version kernel is inappropriate, due to the fact that the kernel is restricted to the provide Starto. So this is the kernel version:

```
3.13.0-042stab111.12
```

That's the old [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132706/docker-service-does-not-start).

Answer (score 8):

Seems like docker is still not supported by Strato v-servers. Running `docker daemon` fails:

```
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
ERRO[0000] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded. 
WARN[0000] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-042stab111.12/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: WARNING: Module bridge not found.
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-042stab111.12/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found.
, error: exit status 1 
WARN[0000] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-042stab111.12/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: WARNING: Module nf_nat not found.`, error: exit status 1 
INFO[0000] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: package not installed
```

Regardless which kernel is installed it starts:

```
Linux h2267479.stratoserver.net 3.13.0-042stab111.12 #1 SMP Thu Sep 17 11:38:20 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Mentioned kernel modules in above error message are not listed by Strato as [supported kernel modules for virtual servers](https://www.strato.de/faq/server/kernel-module-bei-unseren-linux-servern/).

If you need docker you should switch your hoster.

Answer (score 3):

A few weeks ago I did a reinstall of a Strato V-Server from Debian 9 to Ubuntu 18.04 and since then **Docker works**. On the documentation it still says it's not supported, so it might not work on all their infrastructure.

Comment: The [FAQ page](https://www.strato.de/faq/server/welche-server-und-betriebssysteme-bei-strato-sind-docker-ready/) now mentions that docker is supported on V-Server Linux with Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 9

Answer (score 3):

Even if they say that docker is supported, is not working as it should, for example docker swarm mode is not working, and they don't offer any kind of support/advice. They tested that docker was installed, docker search/pull/run commands and they claim that docker is supported. But is not.

Answer (score 1):

Docker on **VPS** (Virtual Private Server) is now **supported** by Strato, but only for Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04. Strato VPS are **Docker ready**, note the following statement:

> Docker can only be used to a limited extent on Linux V servers due to incomplete support from the manufacturer of the virtualization platform.`

The [FAQ](https://www.strato.de/faq/server/welche-server-und-betriebssysteme-bei-strato-sind-docker-ready/) (only in german speech) gives you a good overview, which servers and operating systems have Docker support.

Comment: Docker run works, but Docker swarm produces the error: "please ensure that br_netfilter kernel module is loaded" - this is not the case, and you are not able to do that either