# Error initializing network controller in docker daemon

Tags: linux, docker, daemon

I'm trying to install docker on a virtual server which has OracleLinux 6 by following [Offical docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E75728/html/section_kfy_f2z_fp.html)

I updated my kernel to uekr 4

```
#uname -r
4.1.12-61.1.19.el6uek.x86_64
```

Here's the docker version

```
 #docker version
 Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

When i start the daemon, it gives OK but it dies immediately.

```
#service docker start
Starting docker:        .                                  [  OK  ]
#service docker status
docker dead but subsys locked
```

Here's the logs

```
\nWed Nov 23 07:53:00 GMT 2016\n
time="2016-11-23T07:53:00.610036664Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 5114"
time="2016-11-23T07:53:00.649075962Z" level=warning msg="containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max" current=1024 max=4096
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.690428304Z" level=warning msg="devmapper: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docker` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section."
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.766503952Z" level=warning msg="devmapper: Base device already exists and has filesystem ext4 on it. User specified filesystem  will be ignored."
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.788944031Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"devicemapper\""
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.793561685Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.794228177Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.794714149Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2016-11-23T07:53:01.996320180Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
time="2016-11-23T07:53:02.101877068Z" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default \"bridge\" network: package not installed"
```

It says package not installed but when i run `sudo modinfo bridge`, it shows me the module. Is there any other package I'm missing?

I tried setting env variables in /etc/sysconfig/docker.

I tried installing through binaries.

I tried creating user and adding him to docker group.

I tried many other solutions like

[Docker service does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132706/docker-service-does-not-start)

[Cannot connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971668/cannot-connect-to-docker-daemon)

[Docker command can't connect to Docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562109/docker-command-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

nothing worked!! Can anyone help me?

Comment: Similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759184/oel-6-8-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-t

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_RHEL_6_KVM_Networked_Bridge_Interface How about ```bridge-utils```?

Comment: already installed @Tuan

Comment: In the end I switched to OracleLinux7 and got it working. Still don't know how to fix it in OracleLinux6

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Oracle Linux 6 to test but I belive you got this [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14024). Someone said it's fixed in Docker `1.7.1 RC` but I've not checked it yet.

I'd got the smilar issue on CentOS 6 or RehHat 6. My workaround is install `docker-io-1.6.2-3.el6.x86_64.rpm`, not `docker-engine`.

- Download docker-io package (find at https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/6/x86_64/)
- Need download some other libs for Docker:

Edit yum.repos.d, please edit it base on your Oracle Linux 6

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://www.hop5.in/yum/el6/hop5.repo
yum update
```

- Install the RPM file and start Docker

Like this

```
rpm -ivh docker-io-1.6.2-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
service docker start
```

Comment: didn't get docker-io-1.6.2 in that link but i tried with 1.7.1. same error

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade your OracleLinux to 7 if you want to use Docker. If you can't, you might have to find the package ```docker-io-1.6.2-3.el6.x86_64.rpm``` on internet.